# How can I create a muliti column drop down list with auto complete in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modernizr

This is the sample website, where multiple column is used in dropdown list. I would like to create something like this. Please suggest on this.

https://www.airasiago.com/en-my/

Comment: use [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). The dropdown is created using `div`, `ul` and `li`. You can set the `width` of `ul` as well `li` to show multiple items per line.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ can you provide me some sample code code for achieving this as i am very new to jquery.